# Securing API communication with Oauth

Tags: api, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a REST API that needs to allow CORS for multiple apps, and a single page webapp that should use this API. The API should not be completely open though.

Now, I have looked at different schemes for authentication, and Oauth2 seems like what the "big guys" are using.

The solution I am thinking about implementing is something like this:

The JS webapp makes a request to a local, server side, proxy, which holds the Oauth credentials and obtains a token for the JS webapp to use to communicate directly with the REST API from that point out.

Does this sound viable? I am thinking I just moved the problem, since I now need to validate the webapps token request to the local proxy instead? :)

I am also thinking that this problem must have been solved many times before already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) is meant for authenticating browser applications as you've described. Checkout [Google's Implementation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent) for as an example.